# Custom class is neither appearing in suggestion box of interface builder nor being assigned to View controller

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

I am new in iOS development, I want to assign a custom class to view controller in interface builder but custom class is not appearing in identity inspector of IB although when I import custom class in some other class it does get imported. I Have tried almost everything I found in search like deleting derived data, creating classes with different name and restarting Xcode . But nothing is working. Does any one has some other solution.

Comment: Did you check that your custom class is a subclass of `UIViewController` ?

Comment: Thanks,I checked it was actually NSObject. Now custom class is being assigned. Again thanks for quick reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom view controller class must be a subclass of `UIViewController`.